# Isotope transition 'flash' bug (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, jquery-isotope

I have a filterable grid created using Isotope by Metafizzy.

It's almost working perfectly but there is an issue with content 'flashing' during transitions. If I disable transitions there is no issue so I can only assume the issue is with the transition itself.

I have attached an image of the bug. You can see that the content being shown is a glitch of various elements on the page.

Any advice appreciated!

*EDIT: This appears to be a Chrome specific issue*

**JS**

```
$( function() {
    // Init Isotope
    var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        percentPosition: true,
        transitionDuration: 0.2,
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
            gutter: '.gutter-sizer'
        },
        hiddenStyle: { opacity: 0 },
        visibleStyle: { opacity: 1 }
    });

    // Layout Isotope after each image loads
    $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
        $grid.isotope('layout');
    }); 

    // Bind filter li click
    $('.grid-filter').on( 'click', 'li', function() {
        var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
        $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
    });

    // Add/remove 'current' class on lis
    $('.grid-filter').each( function( i, filters ) {
        var $filters = $( filters );
        $filters.on( 'click', 'li', function() {
            $filters.find('.current').removeClass('current');
            $( this ).addClass('current');
        });
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.grid { position: relative; }

.grid-sizer,
.grid-item { width: calc(50% - 20px); } // 50% - gutter width

.gutter-sizer { width: 20px; }

.grid-item {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    display: flex;
    transition: background 0.4s; /* Prevent double transition jump bug */
}

figure {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-sizer"><!-- Required for sizing blocks --></div>
    <div class="gutter-sizer"><!-- Required for sizing gutter --></div>
    <a href="#" class="grid-item">
        <figure>
            <img src="" />
            <figcaption>
                Content
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
<div>
```

[image: Screengrab]

Comment: Try adding transition to all, instead of just specific properties (`background`, `top` and `left`), and floating item to the left, and then setting it as `display: flex;` makes no sense. Either float it, or use `display: flex;`.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't replicate your problem but wondered if this was just the Chrome flicker issue, considering it is only in chrome? Sometimes there is a weird glitch or flicker with WebKit-powered desktop and mobile browsers when using transitions. You can often fix this by forcing hardware acceleration by adding certain css rules to the element or container of the elements with transitions.

e.g. (you don't need both of these, just one, but typically either of these will work and have no impact on your items visually)

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It was actually just simple styling for me

```
.isotope-wrapper.isotope-loading:before {
  background-color: #ffffff00;
}
```